# Protractor: List remains empty even after I am pushing strings

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to populate a list with Strings that I obtain from my webpage. I only want to add strings if they are not already in the list.

Here is my code (heavily simplified):

```
let globalList = [];
it('should populate list', () => {
     getListOfStrings().then(list => {
         list.map(listItem => {
             if(globalList.indexOf(listItem) === -1){
                  globalList.push(listItem);
             }
         });
     });
     expect(globalList).toBe(["Test", "Test2", "Test3"]);
});
```

The expect statement says that `globalList` remains empty though.
I have made sure the getList() is actually returning a list of strings. And I have tried without the if statement (although I don't see how that would be an issue).
I am relatively new to protractor so sorry if I'm missing anything obvious.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: not familiar with `jasmine` but i think `expect(globalList)` runs before the items are pushed to `globalList` in your callback?

Comment: You should debug your program.

Comment: You were right adiga. All I needed to do was put the expect statement within a 'then' so it waits until the previous actions are resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `expect(globalList)` runs before the items are pushed to `globalList`.
To fix this I added a `then` like so:

```
let globalList = [];
it('should populate list', () => {
     getListOfStrings().then(list => {
         list.map(listItem => {
             if(globalList.indexOf(listItem) === -1){
                  globalList.push(listItem);
             }
         });
     }).then(() => {
         expect(globalList).toBe(["Test", "Test2", "Test3"]);
     })
});
```